# Getting UnmarshalException while creating JAVA objects from xsd for specific xml

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I am using xsd to create java objects using maven-jaxb-plugin (com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2).
 While populating these JAVA Objects from XML file I am getting following error.

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unexpected element "Clients". Expected elements are "{http://www.company.com/enigma/utils/export}Clients".
```

XSD has following structure,

```
targetNamespace="http://www.company.com/enigma/utils/export">
        <xs:element name="Clients">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Client">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Client element represents Client in JSP pages and name attribute for it should be unique</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="column" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="header" use="required"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="metaName" use="required"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="dataType" use="required"/>
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>                  
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="required"/>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="useResource" use="required"/>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="resourceFile" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:unique name="UniqueClientName">
                    <xs:selector xpath="Client"></xs:selector>
                    <xs:field xpath="@name"></xs:field>
                </xs:unique>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and XML is like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Clients xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Client name="ClientDetails" useResource="true">
            <column header="ClientDetails.ClientName" metaName="name" dataType="String"/>
            <column header="ClientDetails.PhysicalAddress" metaName="phyAddress" dataType="String"/>
            <column header="ClientDetails.City" metaName="city" dataType="String"/>
            <column header="ClientDetails.State" metaName="state" dataType="String"/>
    </Client>
</Clients>
```

All the JAXB classes are generated using maven and are in enigma/utils/export folder.
I don't able to solve this issue. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this below code with giving package of generated classes.
 As per your xml it should be **com.enigma.utils.export**

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.enigma.utils.export");
Unmarshaller  unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
```

This may solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you Narendra for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Narendra for your reply. I have used same code in my example. I found out that issue is with target namespace. I added target namespace in xml same as xsd and voila, the error got cleared. Please see xml below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsi:Clients xmlns:xsi=""http://www.company.com/enigma/utils/export"">
    <Client name="ClientDetails" useResource="true">
            <column header="ClientDetails.ClientName" metaName="name" dataType="String"/>
            <column header="ClientDetails.PhysicalAddress" metaName="phyAddress" dataType="String"/>
            <column header="ClientDetails.City" metaName="city" dataType="String"/>
            <column header="ClientDetails.State" metaName="state" dataType="String"/>
    </Client>
</Clients>
```